# Logout user from all browser when password is reset in laravel 5.6

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5.6, reset-password

When the user changes their password, they get Logged Out from the browser. However, if they are logged into another browser at the same time they stay logged in on the other browser.

I want to log out the user from all browsers they are logged into when they reset their password.

Here login controller.

```
function checklogin(Request $request)
{

    $this->validate($request, ['email' => 'required|email', 'password' => 'required|string|min:3']);

    $user_data = array(
        'email' => $request->get('email') ,
        'password' => $request->get('password')
    );

    $remember_me = $request->has('remember') ? true : false;

    if (Auth::attempt($user_data, $remember_me))
    {
        return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
    }
    else
    {
        return back()->with('error', 'Wrong Login Details');
    }
}
```

send mail function as below

```
function sendEmail(Request $request)
{

    $this->validate($request, ['email' => 'required|exists:users']);

    $email = $request->email;

    $name = User::where('email', $email)->first();
    $name = $name->name;

    $token = Password::getRepository()->createNewToken();
    $link = url("password/reset?email=$email&token=$token");

    $value = Password_resets::where('email', $email)->first();

    if (isset($value))
    {
        Password_resets::where('email', $email)->update(['email' => $email, 'token' => $token]);
    }
    else
    {
        Password_resets::insert(['email' => $email, 'token' => $token]);
    }

    Mail::to($email)->send(new \App\Mail\ResetPassword($link, $name));

    return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Please check your Email for Password Reset');
}
```

password reset function as below

```
function resetpasswordchange(Request $request)
{

    $passwordtoken = $request->input('passwordtoken');
    $email = $request->input('email');
    $user_password = $request->input('user_password');

    $users['user'] = Password_resets::where('token', $passwordtoken)->where('email', $email)->get();
    if (empty($users['user'][0]))
    {
        $settoken = '0';

    }
    else
    {
        $settoken = $users['user'][0]->token;

    }

    if (($settoken) == $passwordtoken)
    {

        $update = array(
            'password' => bcrypt($user_password) ,
        );

        User::where('email', $email)->update($update);
       /* Auth::logout();
        auth()->logoutOtherDevices(bcrypt($user_password),'password');*/

        return redirect()->route('login')->with('success', 'Password has been Updated.');

    }
    else
    {
        return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Token & Email Not Match!.');
    }
}
```

How I can logout the user from all browsers who they are logged already ?

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/2444 might helpful for you I think.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open `App\Http\Kernel` and inside the `protected $middlewareGroups` property uncomment the `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class` middleware. This compares the password hash of the user to see if the session is valid or not.

Comment: Why it was commented in the first place? I assume there's a valid reason for that?

Comment: @Vladan probably not the desired behavior by everyone. If you find out something please share it here.